# Casting character varying field into a date

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables,

```
details
 id integer primary key
 onsetdate Date

questionnaires
 id integer primary key
 patient_id integer foreign key
 questdate Character Varying
```

Is it possible to make a SELECT statement that performs a JOIN on these two tables, ordering by the earliest date taken from a comparision of onsetdate and questdate (is it possible for example to cast the questdate into a Date field to do this?)

Typical format for questdate is "2009-04-22"

The actual tables have an encyrpted BYTEA field for the onsetdate - but I'll leave that part until later (the application is written in RoR using 'ezcrypto' to encrypt the BYTEA field).

Comment: A date value in a bytea column? What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: The BYTEA column contains the encrypted date string in the actual database. Reasoning behind it is a very bad excuse to enforce "best practice" regarding Patient Identifiable Data, leading to encrypted fields spread all around this legacy database. Unfortunately this means that the function that was used to preform the encryption is external to PostgreSQL (although I think it does use the OpenSSL library). Comparing the charvar field cast as a Date and an encrypted bytea field would probably be my next question - after I've got my head around the easy stuff :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like

```
  SELECT...
    FROM details d
    JOIN quesionnaires q ON d.id=q.id
ORDER BY LEAST (decrypt_me(onsetdate), questdate::DATE)
```

maybe? i'm not sure about the meaning of 'id', if you want to join by it or something else

By the way, you can leave out the explicit cast, it's in ISO format after all.
I guess you know what to use in place of decrypt_me()

Comment: Ah yeh sorry Rails conventions on how to name the database fields - each table (model) should have an id field, if there's an associated table which links to that model than the corresponding id should be named the singular of the table name followed by "_id". In the Rails model they aren't true foreign keys (at least as far as I understand it) but it's all handled at the application level not the database level.

Comment: eh, the rails activerecord model is broken. very popular, very pop, and a little broken :-)   but postgres is flexible enough to cover a few corners more

Answer (score 1):

There is a date parsing function in postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-formatting.html

Look for the to_timestamp function.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL supports the standard SQL CAST() function. (And a couple others, too.) So you can use

```
CAST (questdate AS DATE)
```

as long as all the values in the column 'questdate' evaluate to a valid date. If this database has been in production for a while, though, that's pretty unlikely. Not impossible, but pretty unlikely.

Comment: Yup that looks like it could be a problem since a number of the questdate fields seem to be populated with spaces (representing an empty date), instead of a NULL.